# MySQL concat question

Tags: mysql, concatenation, summary

I am somewhat mystified by concat and joins in MySQL 4. Here's where I am having an issue.
I have two tables...

```
person

id, fname, lname, city, state, zip


capital

state, city
```

I am needing to generate all states and the number of persons (from the person table) from each. Something like ....

```
AK | 5

AL | 7

AZ | 0
```

etc etc
All states are listed in the capital table but there may be a state like AZ that has no persons.

Any advice would be appreciated. 
I so rarely am asked to do anything MySQL related and I'm stumped.

Lucy

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT   CONCAT(state, ' | ', CAST(count(*) AS CHAR))
FROM     person 
GROUP BY state
```

As per the update, to get the states with 0 persons:

Solution 1:

```
SELECT   CONCAT(state, ' | ', CAST(count(*) AS CHAR))
FROM     person 
GROUP BY state
UNION 
SELECT   CONCAT(state, ' | 0')
FROM     capital
WHERE    NOT EXISTS 
         (SELECT 1 FROM person WHERE capital.state = person.state)
```

Solution 2: Use [outer join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) of 2 tables on state, and do group by state on the outer join results.

Comment: I think it's because there are some states that have 0 persons and that would show as AZ | 0. I edited the question and THANKS for your input. I really appreciate it.